# parsing html table by php script and printing it on our page

Tags: php, html

I have a table [here](http://result.msrit.edu/getresult.php?myusn=1ms10cs410&B1=GET%20RESULT) which is containing some data,So i want to copy that data and wants to print it on my webpage by the php script,So someone please help me out,If u dont mind anyone contribute the suitable code here for this question.

Comment: Consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php/3577662#3577662

Comment: What. Have. You. Tried?

Comment: Does the website with the table/data belong to you?

Comment: Per the flagging menu: _"Questions asking for code **must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**."_ You should consider showing us what you've tried and putting forth a little research effort

Comment: Consider providing your code, or telling us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a DOM Parser like [SimpleHTMLDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('http://result.msrit.edu/getresult.php?myusn=1ms10cs410&B1=GET%20RESULT');
$elems = $html->find("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/th[1]/div"); 

foreach($elems as $v) 
{

//do the parsing here 

}
```

Read the [documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) for the available options and examples.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents ('http://result.msrit.edu/getresult.php?myusn=1ms10cs410&B1=GET%20RESULT'));
$table=$dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
echo $dom->saveHTML($table->item(0));
```